# Can't use components importing HeadlessUI Dialog in a different project

Tags: reactjs, rollup, craco, headless-ui

I'm working in a component library that has a custom `Dialog` component, which uses the `Dialog`from @headlessui/react. The problem is that whenever I try to use this component I get this error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

> ./node_modules/@test/ui-components/dist/ui-components.cjs.development.js/exports.TestDialog@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75318:13

This is the component, if that helps

```
import { Dialog } from '@headlessui/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const TestDialog: React.FC = () => {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
      <p>
        Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? All of your data will
        be permanently removed. This action cannot be undone.
      </p>

      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Deactivate</button>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Cancel</button>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

I have tried changing the `tsconfig` file, adding babel plugins and multiple things but nothing seems to work.

This is only happening in a project using `craco`, but works on other `NextJS` projects.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please consider adding the code where the warning occurs. You will only get wild guesses without it.

Comment: It's not a specific line, just importing and placing the component anywhere causes the error

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when a component returns undefined. Perhaps some component inside that Dialog component returns undefined. To fix this, Check all your `return` statements.  You have to at least return `null` inside a component.

from

```
export Component = () => {
   return;
}
```

to

```
export Component = () => {
  return null
}
```

Comment: I added the component to the question, that shouldn't happen. If it didn't work in any project it would make sense, but that it doesn't work only in this one is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example from the [headless ui docs](https://headlessui.com/react/dialog#basic-example) you can see that they have all their dialog content wrapped in a `<Dialog.Panel>` component.

Without that you'll find your component doesn't render anything which I believe is what is causing your error.

If you change your component to the below I think it should work.

```
import { Dialog } from '@headlessui/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const TestDialog: React.FC = () => {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
      <Dialog.Panel>
        <p>
          Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? All of your 
          data will be permanently removed. This action cannot be undone.
        </p>

        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Deactivate</button>
        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Cancel</button>
      </Dialog.Panel>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are on the latest version of `@headlessui/react`

```
npm install @headlessui/react@latest
```

see issue solved [github issue solved](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/1419)